# Как можно сделать, чтобы при перезагрузки в блоке отображался новый текст?

Tags: php

Здравствуйте. Вопрос в следующем:

Из базы данных вытаскиваются отзывы и показываются на странице. Как можно сделать так, при перезагрузке страницы каждый раз показывался новый отзыв? То есть чтобы из базы вытаскивался новый отзыв при перезагрузке?

Comment: Вроде бы на вопрос ответили, но ответа почему-то не вижу.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Случайный отзыв? Делайте запрос из БД случайной записи: SELECT что_надо FROM откуда ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT сколько_надо.
Про оптимизацию такого типа выборки в рунете полно информации.

Comment: Спасибо. Сейчас поищу в нете.